# Smooth approximation of $\max(f_1(x),f_2(x),\cdots,f_n(x))$

Tags: nonlinear-programming, approximation

In the GAMS documentation concerning non-smooth optimization I found the following statement:

> A smooth approximation for $\max(f(x),g(y))$ is as in the following example code:
>
> `[f(x) + g(y) + sqrt(sqr(f(x)-g(y)) + sqr(delta))] /2` where `delta` a small number.

Does something similar exist for $\max(f_1(x),f_2(x),\cdots,f_n(x))$?

Comment: Depending on how you want to use the $\max$, you might be able to linearize exactly.

Comment: $\max\left(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n\right) = \max\left(x_0,\max\left(x_1,\max\left(\ldots,x_n\right)\right)\right) .$

Comment: @RobPratt Hi Rob, I would like to avoid ending up with an MILP because of  the difficulties associated with MILPs. The question is if I can win anything out of staying in the NLP domain. Probably not, because I will have to deal with a global optimization problem, but I would like to give it a try.

Comment: @Nat That is going to be a nightmare when it comes to implemention.

Comment: @Clement You do not necessarily require integer variables for linearization. Where does the $\max$ appear in your problem?

Comment: @RobPratt It is a set of constraints in the form $Max (x_1,..,x_n) = f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ where $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ is a linear function. I can linearize these constraints as explained for example [here](https://www.fico.com/en/resource-access/download/3217) getting a MILP. The formulation doesn´t help me in avoiding an MILP model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, there exists numerous smooth approximations for the max function.
One of the most well known approximation is the Kreisselmeier-Steinhauser (KS) functional, that approximates the non-smooth functional
$$
\max(f_1(x), \cdots, f_n(x))
$$
with the smooth functional
$$
KS(f_1, \cdots, f_n; \rho) = \frac{1}{\rho} \log{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i e^{\rho f_i} } 
= \max_i f_i \; + \; \frac{1}{\rho} \log{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i e^{\rho (f_i - \max_i(f_i))} } 
$$
with $\rho>0$ and $w_1, \cdots, w_n$ given (positive) weights.

This functional satisfies:

- $KS(f_1, \cdots, f_n; \rho) > \max_i(f_i)$ for all $\rho >0$
- $\lim_{\rho \to +\infty} KS(f_1, \cdots, f_n; \rho) \to \max_i(f_i)$
- $\max_i(f_i) < KS(f_1, \cdots, f_n; \rho) \leq \max_i(f_i) + \frac{\log(n)}{\rho} $

You could find more details about the KS functional in

> Polyak, R. A. "Smooth optimization methods for minimax problems." SIAM Journal on Control and Optimization 26.6 (1988): 1274-1286.